# UIImageView rotation animation with easy out

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I am rotating a round arrow at the moment round in round in circles.. This is cool and all but I am wanting to have something a little more polished when it comes to ending like other views where you can animate them to ease in or out, I was wondering if you can do the same for this.. this is my code as it stands..

```
- (IBAction)animator:(id)sender
{
    [arrowRotation removeFromSuperview];

    //arrow animation
    arrowRotation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    arrowRotation.frame = CGRectMake(148.0, 20.0, 30.0, 30.0);
    [self.view addSubview:arrowRotation];



    CABasicAnimation *fullRotation;
    fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.duration = 0.75f;
    fullRotation.repeatCount = 3;

    [arrowRotation.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
}
```

So my question is can I make this animation slow down when it comes to the 3 rotation.. like an ease out of a UIView. if that makes sense..

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First off, in this line `fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];`, your float `((360*M_PI)/180)` will rotate the circle 360 degrees, but your numbers are a little excessive. What I mean by this is that you can simplify it to `2*M_PI`.

Second: If you want to customize this more, you can use a `CAKeyframeAnimation`:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];

NSArray *rotationValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat: (2*M_PI)], nil];

[rotationAnimation setValues:rotationValues];

NSArray *rotationTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];
[rotationAnimation setKeyTimes:rotationTimes];

NSArray *rotationTimingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear],[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut],  nil];
[rotationAnimation setTimingFunctions:rotationTimingFunctions];

rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
rotationAnimation.duration = 1;

[self.view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"animation"];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool thanks for helping me understand things better.. I still don't think its achiving the easy out I am looking for but thats okay.. I am still trying to learn animation stuff.. I have only ever done basic calls to UIViews etc.. I want to get into some cool stuff now that I have some time but just wanna make sure I am doing things correctly..l thanks for the help.

Comment: @HurkNburkS If you have any further questions about the code or don't understand something, feel free to ask.

Comment: Cool man, thanks heaps.. just reading through some of the functions in the ios Library now.. I should be sweet.. but if I do I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` to do the animations and use the option `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut`.  This is the updated, preferred UIView animation method on iOS, and will let you do the ease out you want.

Docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Good suggestion. Although UIView's `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method is the preferred animation method for UIView animations, **it** **is** **not** the overall preferred animation method. The best animation methods are the ones in the Core Animation and OpenGL frameworks, as they are hardware accelerated, allowing for more complex animations without worrying about performance.